# I can't see where is all of my disk memory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

I have a disk partition where the Linux/Ubuntu system is installed. It was orginally made to posses 254 GB, but currently it's just 194 GB. I've got no idea what have happened recently that I can't see all of it now. I suspect that is has something with using docker recently or external hard drive, because I recently change name of it and I don't know why but my system started to iterating new External Disk whit each system restart and hold in folder /home/media. Anyway I should somehow check where is all the left memory or the disk analyzer doesn't see all folders and I don't know how to run it as root. To illustrate the problem these are screen shots:
[image]

Comment: What does ‘df /‘ say?  Can also try ‘sudo du -s /‘ and see what that says

Comment: df / say : 
Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on /dev/nvme0n1p6 248753164 220599920 15447556 94%

I run command "sudo baobab" to  see usage analyzer on sudo, and now I can see usage of 225 GB. There's a lot of memory taken by Docker and other smaller stuffI didnt see previously. I think the problem is solved now